# mapbox api get all features c#

Tags: c#, mapbox

since their is no framework for c# within regards to mapbox which supports features.

what is the best way to get all the features from a dataset.

current implementation which can retrieve 184 features of the 500+ (this is expected to increase to about 8000+)

```
        string user = " < MY USER >";
        string DataSetID = "< MY DATA SET>";
        string token = " < MY TOKEN STRING ( instyle of ?access_token= a key" );
        string total = "&limit=542";
        string start = "start=4f0f"; // the last feature ID out of the default pull 
        var client = new RestClient();

        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/");


        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Resource = user + "/" + DataSetID + "/features/"+ start + token ;
 < Also tried limit >
 request.Resource = user + "/" + DataSetID + "/features/"+ total + token ;
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var ListFeatures= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response.Content);
        return ListFeatures;
```

How should I go about getting back all the features within a dataset ?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? you are not explaining why you can retrieve only (i assume) 184 features?

Answer (score 0):

i logged back into stack overflow and noticed I had a problem up here,

I answered it by taking 100 features at a time kinda like a cursor and just moving up until it took less then 100 features.

btw everything i posted is complete garbage.